# Javascript's confirm dialog shows wrong text

Tags: javascript, magento, translation

we are developing a Magento Webstore. I got a very weird bug going on and it has to do with Javascript's confirm box.

See this image to see the difference between the confirm box content and the a href with the translated text in the confirm box https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGhzD.png

The translated text is visible in the Google element inspector, but the original English text is shown instead.

Does anybody know about this bug? Or maybe i'm not aware of something really simple :P. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you checked that the onclick handler is actually being called? It is most likely that you've added multiple onclick handlers, for instance, through jQuery. That could override the one that is on there already in the HTML tag. Edit: Magento does do this, with a rather complicated set of scripts, using Prototype.js, not jQuery.

Comment: Thanks Steven, I forgot to check that. I use a theme and they overwrite the click event T.T Thanks for pointing it out. I got a tunnelvision on the google element inspector.

Answer (score 0):

in the Google element inspector that you show there is:

```
<a href="your URL" ... onClick="return confirm('your translated text')" ... >
```

This means that that you call the confirm function with the translated text as an argument.

You should show us or examine yourself the definition of the 
    function confirm

to understand why you are not seeing what you are expecting.

If you are using the http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp function, I would suggest to double check that you are looking into correct element in the HTML inspector:
First open the inspector, then find the element that you are going to click, check its HTML code, and then click that element to open the the confirmation dialog.

The confirm function cannot translate the text that you show us in the inspector to the text that you show us in the confirmation dialog (unless you have some kind of translation filter applied, but that doesn't seem to be the case).

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp this function, the default javascript one, and its in the inspector.. thats what needs to be shown to the user then, isn't it. The definition is here: http://i.imgur.com/HLXv25f.png where $this->__('Blabla') is a translated string. And as you can see, it returns actually the right string, but it shows the default english string.